# Are SQLite result sets in-memory data structures?

Tags: sql, sqlite, resources

I currently find myself needing to do fairly simple computations on several million datapoints. (Constructing a large list of strings from a well defined multi-gigabite file, sorting that list, and then comparing it to another list, a superset.) This is the sort of simple work most of us normally do with the data entirely in-memory, but the size and quantity of the units of data I need to work with could make RAM an issue if I try to keep everything in memory. I quickly realized I probably need to write the data to a file, at a few points, to avoid exhausting my system's resources. I decided to use SQLite3 for this. (This is probably a bit much for a CSV.) It is fairly lightweight, while its storage limits seem to safely exceed my requirements.

The problem I am having is the understanding exactly how the result set works. The documentation I have come across seems a little vague on this. Obviously, SQLite is not writing a whole new table to the database every time a SELECT statement is executed. Does this mean it is duplicating all the selected fields in a complete in-memory table, or does it only keep some sort of pointers in memory (rather than the actual data)? Something else altogether?

I need to be able to sort the data in question. If the result set is really just an in-memory data structure, than simply creating creating a new table and populating it with the help of ORDER BY could be a bad idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite does not really have result sets. It has cursors, which allow access to only the current row, and which cannot go backwards.

SQLite computes results on the fly, so only one row needs to be in memory at a time.

When a computation needs to access multiple rows (i.e., aggregate functions, or sorting without a usable index), as much data as possible is kept in the [cache](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_cache_size), and then spilled to disk in a [temporary database](http://www.sqlite.org/tempfiles.html).